# Как вывести строчку по частям

Tags: java

Есть строка в текстовом файле:

```
"0  0,21875 -0,02625    0,3625  -1,091  -4,7875 6,875   13,5
            -0,0225 -0,05125    -0,0135625"
```

Нужно, чтобы каждая подстрока, являющийся цифрой, вводилась в отдельную переменную, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?..

Comment: Разбейте строку по пробелам на массив строк и присвойте его элементы нужным вам переменным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а можно так извратиться:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "0  0,21875 -0,02625    0,3625  -1,091  -4,7875 6,875   13,5\n" +
            "            -0,0225 -0,05125    -0,0135625";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes())));
    List<Float> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        numbers.add(scanner.nextFloat());
    }
}
```

Добавил со Scanner( String )

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "0  0,21875 -0,02625    0,3625  -1,091  -4,7875 6,875   13,5\n" +
            "            -0,0225 -0,05125    -0,0135625";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
    List<Float> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        numbers.add(scanner.nextFloat());
    }
}
```

Comment: @zRrr, со Scanner( String ) ещё красивее

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить массив из `double`

```
public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "0  0,21875 -0,02625    0,3625  -1,091  -4,7875 6,875   13,5\n" +
                    "            -0,0225 -0,05125    -0,0135625";
            String[] strToDoubleArray = (str.replaceAll(",", ".")).split("\\s+");
            double[] doubleArray = new double[strToDoubleArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < strToDoubleArray.length; i++) {
                doubleArray[i] = Double.valueOf(strToDoubleArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

И затем использовать элементы искомого массива `doubleArray` как вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

**Как вариант можно так:**

```
 public static double[] readFile(String path) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
            return Files.lines(Paths.get(ReadFile.class.getResource(path).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())
                    .mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)
                    .toArray();
    }
```

Comment: отличный вариант, для большей пуленепробиваемости можно указать в split регулярку `\\s+`

Answer (score 0):

```
        String [] str_tr;
        String delimeter = "\t"; // Разделитель
        str_tr = str_track.split(delimeter);
```

Решила проблему таким образом.

Comment: Если решать проблему через разделитель \t, его придется указать как "\\t". Но срока должна содержать разделители в виде "a\tb\t", а в условии только пробелы.

Comment: совсем забыл про StringTokenizer. `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            String nextStr = st.nextToken();
        }` Здесь разделителями будет и табуляция, и пробел и перенос строки.